# Problem with dynamically loading SVG in Nuxt3

Tags: javascript, typescript, svg, vite, nuxt3

Building Nuxt3 project currently, I have added 'vite-svg-loader' plugin to dynamically load SVG's.The following code works fine:

```
...
<Logo/>
...
import Logo from `~/assets/logo.svg`
```

Now, I am trying to build a component for dynamic loading of icons, so that I can do `<Icon name="arrow" />`

In the template, I have:

```
<component :is="icon" />
```

In the script, I have:

```
onMounted(async () => {
  await importIcon()
})
...
watch(() => props.name, async () => await importIcon)
...
async function importIcon() {
  try {
    icon.value = await import(`~/assets/icons/${props.name}.svg`)
  } catch (err) {
    icon.value = await import(`~/assets/icons/_blank.svg`)
  }
}
...
```

The problem is, that it results in the following error. `TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier '~/assets/icons/arrow.svg' at importIcon`

What is more confusing, the blank gets loaded OK in the catch block, but will fail if passed via props. I tried names without '-', nothing helps. This worked perfectly fine in Nuxt2 using `require(...)`.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using the `defineAsyncComponent` method as presented in the docs https://vuejs.org/guide/components/async.html#basic-usage?

Comment: I did, but it created other issues. In the end, I had to provide relative path `icon.value = await import(\`../../assets/icons/${props.name}.svg\`)` Tilde was the problem. It does work with _blank though, when there is no string concatenation.

Comment: Nice ! The aliases seems to have issues from time to time in vite. This article explains a neat way to handle the situation as well: https://dev.to/greggcbs/vite-dynamic-import-in-vue-3-and-nuxt-3-29n5